# When do I release an NSMutableArray instance passed to multiple methods?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have the following scenario:

```
class1
methodA
NSMutableArray *myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[class2 methodB:myArray];
[myArray release];
...

class2
methodB:(NSMutableArray) myArray{
[class3 methodB:myArray];
}
...

class3
methodC:(NSMutableArray) myArray{
  manipulate contents of myArray...
}
...
```

Is it appropriate to release myArray JUST in methodA or should I release it in each methodB and methodC? I want all three methods to have access to the same contents, i.e., it is the same array being accessed in each method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not own `myArray` in `methodB` or `methodC` (that is you have not retained in that methods) then don't release in those methods. You own the array only in first method via `alloc`, so you release it only in `methodA`. So your approach is correct.